# Modulus Problem: $|x+1| - |x| + 3|x-1| -2|x-2| = x+2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, absolute-value

I do not understand how to solve such a question:

$$|x+1| - |x| + 3|x-1| -2|x-2| = x+2.$$

How would you go about all the possibilities with which sign the modulus could take?
Appreciate any help!

Comment: I think this should be re-opened (even though it has an answer) because there's a maths question here!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Addendum: The first case.

For $x\le 1$ as mentioned ALL of the expressions in the $|\cdot|$ are negative, so the expression takes the form:

$$-(x+1)+x-3(x-1)+2(x-2)$$
$=-x-2$ after tidying up. This is valid as long as $-\infty<x\le -1$ - which the diagram confirms.

It is easy to see that $x+2$ and $-x-2=-(x+2)$ intersect at $x=-2$ - the first one is found for you

---

A picture is worth 1000 words:

[image]
All you have to do is check at the cases where these functions switch. So for example with $x\le -1$ ALL of the modulus parts are the negative of their internal values.

For $x\in[0,1]$ the first one is just $x+1$ and the other 3 are all negatives of their internal values,

carry forward with this process.

You are in effect finding the line segments in the diagram below.

Comment: If you get really stuck I can do the first 2 for you. But I will flesh this out a bit with the first one.

Comment: I strongly encourage the OP to actually sketch his progress. Sketches always help.

Comment: What does OP mean? And yes I understand what you have done there but then say you made the first two modulus parts positive and the last two negative then wouldnt that cause the graph to change as well?

Comment: @user258521 OP:=Original poster

Comment: @user258521 OP means *you*, the **original poster**. Have you not tried anything at all on this problem??? It seems like all you want is for other people to do your work. What are your thoughts on the matter? Have you tried anything?

Comment: @DanielW.Farlow fear not, I shall not do the ENTIRE problem for him.

Comment: Thank you, I am new to this site and just have no clue on where to start with the problem and do not understand the solution I have been given so wanted other people to provide me with a different input

Comment: @user258521 the first 2 are only negative for $-1\le x\le 0$ - so it's a different line on each portion.

Comment: I think I finally have got it, thanks for the help and it says i get an error when I upvote your comments

Comment: @user258521 having one upvote and a tick to give is fine. Glad I could help.